# image brightness taking too much time for click

Tags: android, bitmap

Hi In my application am displaying some themes .In that theme when am pressing any image that image background will turn to give little bit more brighter compared to remaining all the themes.

Now, My issue is while pressing the image it is taking too much work on main thread.How to do while pressing the image fast touch should happens.

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue.

sample.java:

```
 mTick1.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.classic),-80));
                mTick2.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.casual1),-0));
                mTick3.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.natural),-0));
                mTick4.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smart),-0));
                mTick5.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.meeting),-0));
                mTick6.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cool),-0));
                mTick1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTick2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTick3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTick4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTick5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTick6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTick6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Brightness method:

```
public Bitmap SetBrightness(Bitmap src, int value) {
        // original image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // scan through all pixels
        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);

                // increase/decrease each channel
                R += value;
                if(R > 255) { R = 255; }
                else if(R < 0) { R = 0; }

                G += value;
                if(G > 255) { G = 255; }
                else if(G < 0) { G = 0; }

                B += value;
                if(B > 255) { B = 255; }
                else if(B < 0) { B = 0; }

                // apply new pixel color to output bitmap
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }

        // return final image
        return bmOut;
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations

Comment: Hi Nudge anything can i do using my code